# Using a react native module with a native android code

Tags: java, android, react-native

I wrote a simple Toast module by using react native modules. I've uploaded it to github. I can install it in my hybrid app by using this command.

> npm i --save git+https://github.com/akulkarni9/ToastModule.git

Then I can link it to my hybrid app by using below code.

```
include ':ToastModule'
project(':ToastModule').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../node_modules/ToastModule/android')
```

This is simple and straighforward.
But I'm looking at something else. I've a native android app, i.e., a project written in pure java. Now I want to add that react native module to that java android project. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: You can use `react-native-link`

Comment: No, I'm talking about `non-react-native` projects that are based on pure `java` or `kotlin` which doesn't have `node-modules` in it.

Comment: You need to refer to this official document. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android